# Platform to use in creating games

Tags: flash

What platform is good to use to creating games with genres like mind games, puzzles and the likes.. we are just beginners and we can't decide what platform to use.
Please help. And may I ask for references. Thank you :)

Comment: this question should go to the stackexchange for software recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the platform you are targeting. I've done some work with [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) in the past, and the free version allows for web publishing. If you then expand to iOS, Android, or another platform it supports, you pay for the license to publish.

Adobe Flash isn't bad, as I'm sure you know based on the tag of this post, though you will have to purchase the program from Adobe to publish anything legally.

I've heard some good things about [GameMaker Studio](http://store.steampowered.com/app/214850/), but don't know much about it, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Mobile web rich Internet app using jquery and spine.js or backbone.js on browser and node.js with express.js and mongoose/mongo on server hosted on heroku. One language, easy hosting, fun to program, fast to deploy.

Comment: If the game is people playing together within the browser, e.g words with friends style, check into Derby.js specifically, which is all about massively real-time interaction.  This blog matched my impression, http://ocdevel.com/blog/derby-meteor-holy-sh-programming-just-got-easy